# SonarQube - C++ - Ubunbtu - build-wrapper LD_PRELOAD Error

Tags: c++, sonarqube, ubuntu-18.04

I just upgraded my linux build slaves and since then my sonarqube stopped working.

Run to reproduce:

```
docker run -it ubuntu:18.04 bash
apt-get update
apt-get install wget unzip
wget 192.168.1.5:9000/static/cpp/build-wrapper-linux-x86.zip
unzip build-wrapper-linux-x86.zip
cd build-wrapper-linux-x86
./build-wrapper-linux-x86-64 --out-dir test ls

ERROR: ld.so: object '/build-wrapper-linux-x86/libinterceptor-${PLATFORM}.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
```

Docker images 16.04, 16.10 are working, 17.10, 18.04 are not working.
The PLATFORM env variable is empty, but i guess it is exported by the build-wrapper script.
 Anyone any idea?

Comment: issue was solved on sonarcube forum: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-c-ubuntu-build-wrapper-ld-preload-error/300/11